# Horizontal and vertical alignment in a flexbox table

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to build a responsive table-based calendar with one column (`.calendar-arrow`) that is vertically centered next to the other columns.

I'm also trying to left-align the month/date heading with the first column (Sunday column) without using a static padding value.

I'm open to restructuring the HTML.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#event-calendar {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1%;
  overflow: auto;
}
#event-calendar h1 {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
#event-calendar #calendar-left {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 400px;
}
#event-calendar #calendar-right {
  float: right;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 400px;
}
#event-calendar .table .table-row .table-cell {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: black;
}
#event-calendar .table .table-header .table-cell {
  color: grey;
}
.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
.table .table-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
}
.table .table-row .table-cell {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
  justify-content: center;
}
.table .table-row .event-on {
  position: relative;
}
.table .table-row .event-on::before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -9;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  content: '';
}
.table .calendar-arrow {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="event-calendar">
  <div id="calendar-left">
    <div id="calendar-left-cont">
      <h1>December 2016</h1>
      <div class="table">
        <div class="calendar-arrow">
          &larr;
        </div>
        <div class="table-row table-header">
          <div class="table-cell">S</div>
          <div class="table-cell">M</div>
          <div class="table-cell">T</div>
          <div class="table-cell">W</div>
          <div class="table-cell">T</div>
          <div class="table-cell">F</div>
          <div class="table-cell">S</div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-row">
          <div class="table-cell"></div>
          <div class="table-cell"></div>
          <div class="table-cell event-on">1</div>
          <div class="table-cell">2</div>
          <div class="table-cell">3</div>
          <div class="table-cell">4</div>
          <div class="table-cell">5</div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-row">
          <div class="table-cell">6</div>
          <div class="table-cell">7</div>
          <div class="table-cell">8</div>
          <div class="table-cell">9</div>
          <div class="table-cell">10</div>
          <div class="table-cell">11</div>
          <div class="table-cell">12</div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-row">
          <div class="table-cell">13</div>
          <div class="table-cell">14</div>
          <div class="table-cell">15</div>
          <div class="table-cell">16</div>
          <div class="table-cell">17</div>
          <div class="table-cell">18</div>
          <div class="table-cell">19</div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-row">
          <div class="table-cell">20</div>
          <div class="table-cell">21</div>
          <div class="table-cell">22</div>
          <div class="table-cell">23</div>
          <div class="table-cell">24</div>
          <div class="table-cell">25</div>
          <div class="table-cell">26</div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-row">
          <div class="table-cell">27</div>
          <div class="table-cell">28</div>
          <div class="table-cell">29</div>
          <div class="table-cell">30</div>
          <div class="table-cell"></div>
          <div class="table-cell"></div>
          <div class="table-cell"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="calendar-right">
    <div id="calendar-right-cont">
      <h1>January 2017</h1>
      <div class="table">
        <div class="table-row table-header">
          <div class="table-cell">S</div>
          <div class="table-cell">M</div>
          <div class="table-cell">T</div>
          <div class="table-cell">W</div>
          <div class="table-cell">T</div>
          <div class="table-cell">F</div>
          <div class="table-cell">S</div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-row">
          <div class="table-cell"></div>
          <div class="table-cell"></div>
          <div class="table-cell">1</div>
          <div class="table-cell">2</div>
          <div class="table-cell">3</div>
          <div class="table-cell">4</div>
          <div class="table-cell">5</div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-row">
          <div class="table-cell">6</div>
          <div class="table-cell">7</div>
          <div class="table-cell">8</div>
          <div class="table-cell">9</div>
          <div class="table-cell">10</div>
          <div class="table-cell">11</div>
          <div class="table-cell">12</div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-row">
          <div class="table-cell">13</div>
          <div class="table-cell">14</div>
          <div class="table-cell">15</div>
          <div class="table-cell">16</div>
          <div class="table-cell">17</div>
          <div class="table-cell">18</div>
          <div class="table-cell">19</div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-row">
          <div class="table-cell">20</div>
          <div class="table-cell">21</div>
          <div class="table-cell">22</div>
          <div class="table-cell">23</div>
          <div class="table-cell">24</div>
          <div class="table-cell">25</div>
          <div class="table-cell">26</div>
        </div>
        <div class="table-row">
          <div class="table-cell">27</div>
          <div class="table-cell">28</div>
          <div class="table-cell">29</div>
          <div class="table-cell">30</div>
          <div class="table-cell"></div>
          <div class="table-cell"></div>
          <div class="table-cell"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="calendar-arrow">
          &rarr;
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Pen: http://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/ENJOLO

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To vertically center the arrows you can use absolutely positioned pseudo elements, instead of arrows in actual DOM elements.

Remove the arrows from the HTML and add this to your CSS:

```
div.table {
  position: relative;
}
#calendar-left div.table::before {
   content: "\2190";
   position: absolute;
   left: -30px;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   font-size: 2em;
}
#calendar-right div.table::before {
   content: "\2192";
   position: absolute;
   left: -30px;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   font-size: 2em;
}
```

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zoXMVb)

The reason your day-header row isn't left-aligning with your month-year `h1` is that you have the header row centered with `justify-content: center`.

```
.table-cell {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

This centers the data within each column, but doesn't apply to the `h1`.

You would have to align both elements along the left edge of their mutual container:

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RoOENG?editors=1100)

Or you could remove the centering:

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KNYrOR)

Comment: Thanks for the arrow solution. I noticed this effect of `justify-content: center`, but I'm intentionally using it to center single digits above/below double.

Comment: You're centering the column data in the calendar, but the `h1` isn't associated with this alignment because it exists in a different container. The only way to left-align them would be in their mutual container. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RoOENG?editors=1100

Comment: I see what you mean. For a second, I thought they were visually aligned, but then I realised it appeared this way because of the borders. I've tried placing the `h1` in the same `div` as the first cell, but they sit on the same line. Also, I think I should stick to a DOM element for the arrows as they'll need to be nav hyperlinks.

Comment: Ah, yes. I probably should have left the arrow in the DOM. You can still absolutely position it like the pseudo-element. Should be a minor adjustment.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll definitely consider it. For now, just following the designer's template.